# Batch file: Copy files with a last directory into another directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory that has XX subfolders and close to YY files within those subfolders (up to ZZ layers). The files are `.jpg` or `.png`, and each extension has a unique file name. I need to copy the files to the root (into another directory) without recreating the subfolder structure like `xcopy` does, BUT with a last folder.

**Existing:**

```
Dir1\Folder1\Holiday.jpg
Dir1\Folder3\Picture.png
Dir1\Folder3\Mobile.jpg
Dir1\Folder3\Dir2\000114.jpg
Dir1\Folder3\Dir2\000115.jpg
Dir1\Folder3\Dir2\000116.jpg
Dir1\Folder5\Dir3\A.jpg
Dir1\Folder5\Dir3\B.png
Dir1\Folder5\Dir3\Dir4\a1.jpg
Dir1\Folder5\Dir3\Dir4\b12.png
Dir1\Folder5\Dir3\Dir4\c45.jpg
```

**Required:**

```
Dir1\Holiday.jpg
Folder3\Picture.png
Folder3\Mobile.jpg
Dir2\000114.jpg
Dir2\000115.jpg
Dir2\000116.jpg
Dir3\A.jpg
Dir3\B.png
Dir4\a1.jpg
Dir4\b12.png
Dir4\c45.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you getting started:

the first for loop enumerates the whole directory structure. %%i will be the complete path to the file.
The second for loop is simply used to look at the directory path excluding the last '\' so it looks like a full path to a file!

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /r %%i in (*) do (
    set pt=%%~pi
    for %%j in ("!pt:~0,-1!") do (
        echo LastDir=%%~nxj
        echo Filename=%%~nxi
        echo.
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you are a true master. I only added the following:
- quotation marks for path names with spaces: copy "%%i" "%%~nxj";
- Function exist:  if not exist "%%~nxj" md "%%~nxj"


Jan E. Purkinje University